# Design question: should I use template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

*Since my previous question got closed because it was opinion-based, let me copy paste and add additional information for my use case.*

This is more of a design question rather than a programming one.

I have a class that represents something. Suppose this class has certain member variables and functions.

Now, suppose I need some of these functions but others I need to reimplement because they need different mathematical formulas to be computed. Also assume that I need different variables.

Should I specialize the class and reimplement the common functions?
Or is there another approach I am unaware of?
Inheritance is clearly not an option, because I do not need the same variables.
I thought about specializing the single functions too, but the issue is again that I need different variables.

How do I decide? Also: do I really need to reimplement all common functionalities, or is there something I can do to avoid this?

**EDIT**: Since this was considered an opinion-based question, here's my case.
I am implementing a mathematical representation of a vector. Currently, the draft is done and it contains all functions that I need.

Now, I would like to make sure that this vector can be represented in different coordinate systems. For example, one vector might be in cartesian coordinates, another in polar coordinates, another in another coordinate system.

The current vector implementation allows multiple dimensions and types. For the cartesian-system vector, I would only need 2D vectors and two single coordinates. For a polar vector, I would again need 2D vectors but with different coordinate types (For example a cartesian vector has two points as variables; a polar vector has a point and an angle).

This means that I then need to reimplement certain functions. Consider, for example, that the cartesian vector dot product formula differs from that of a polar vector dot product.

**Having a common base class would be indeed ideal, but I'm not sure if there is some common functionality between *all* of the different vectors which might be based on different coordinate systems**.

Some code to let you understand my question follows.
A normal vector looks something like:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
    class Vector {

    private:
        T _vector[Size]{};
    public:
        // all the functions here
```

A polar vector, on the other hand, might look something like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
    class Vector {

    private:
        T coord; 
        T angle; 
    public:
        // Some functions differ from the original vector,
        // Some other functions have the same implementation.
```

... And so on. Note that for spherical vectors, I'd again have different data members, but some common functions. The same applies for other coordinate systems.

Comment: This sounds like a case for polymorphism.  Make a `vector` base class that has the functional interface and then create derived types like `polar_vector` and `spherical_vector` that derive from `vector` and virtually overload the function declared in the base class.

Comment: @NathanOliver would you consider appropriate using polymorphism for a mathematical library? This is a honest question by the way, I am really wondering whether this would be OK.

Comment: No. The virtual calls are slow and conversion on every operation even more so and imprecise. You should make 2 classes with conversion operators so you only convert at most once on input and at most once on output but your algorithm run with the vector type they were made for.

Comment: So I am not sure I am following. Should I go with template specialization and have a common base with common functionalities if possible? @GoswinvonBrederlow

Comment: I agree with @GoswinvonBrederlow that virtual calls are too slow for your specific problem (if you care about efficiency at all). You may make vectors with cartesian and polar coordinates separate classes convertible to each other, or make them the same class template. In the latter case, you may make a template specialization for the entire class or for some components. This is an implementation detail - you need to design the interface first. More generally, I would look for an existing library for this mathematics.

Comment: The first is an array-like-vector, the second is a coordinate-like-vector.  Not the same kind of things.

Comment: Is there even a formula for vector addition for polar vectors? Or vector multiplication and cross product? Does a matrix of polar vectors make sense? Can I transpose that?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow yes, many operations should be defined for polar vectors. The cross product is only defined on 3D, so I dont think it would apply there.

Comment: @Eljay can you then elaborate on what youd do?

Comment: For a case like that, I think the best solution would be to do like the STL with free functions for algorithms... and use templates on algorithms as appropriate. In some cases, overloading a function or an operator might be all you need without templates...

Comment: Considering you yourself can clearly think of several _correct_ implementations, and you're only undecided on which is better (in some extremely vague sense), this is still pretty much opinion based.

Comment: Form follows function.  I would determine what I need the code to do.  Then I'd design the code to fulfill those needs.  Then I'd refactor the code to not suck.  Then I'd add unit tests (apologies to TFD folks, I acknowledge you are better than me).

Comment: It sounds like you're mainly considering 2D and 3D polar vectors? Probably best to use a full math library (Eigen) and define conversions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67116835